# Python code to compute three square theorum

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

A positive integer m can be expresseed as the sum of three squares if it is of the form p + q + r where p, q, r ≥ 0, and p, q, r are all perfect squares. For instance, 2 can be written as 0+1+1 but 7 cannot be expressed as the sum of three squares. The first numbers that cannot be expressed as the sum of three squares are 7, 15, 23, 28, 31, 39, 47, 55, 60, 63, 71, … (see Legendre's three-square theorem).

Write a Python function squares(m) that takes an integer m as input and returns True if m can be expressed as the sum of three squares and False otherwise. (If m is not positive, your function should return False.)

Comment: Is this your homework ? Please show what you have tried.

Comment: Where are you getting stuck on this?

Answer (score 2):

You mention Legendre's three-square theorem. That gives a condition for a number n to be expressible as the sum of three squares: if n != 4^a(8b+7).

That gives a simple O(log(n)) test, used here to print the numbers less than 500 that aren't the sum of three squares.

```
def is_3square(n):
    while n > 0 and n % 4 == 0:
        n //= 4
    return n % 8 != 7

for i in range(500):
    if not is_3square(i):
        print(i, end=', ')
print()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an NPTEL Question. I found it tricky at the first now I'm through with it.

```
def threesquares(n):
    list1=[]
    flag=False
    for i in range(0,100):
        for j in range(0,100):
            tempVar=(4^i)*(8*j)
            list1.append(tempVar)
    if n not in list1 and n > 0:
        flag = True
    else:
        flag = False
    return(flag)
```

Comment: `^` is not exponentation, it's xor.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
failed = set( 7, 15, 23, 28, 31, 39, 47, 55, 60, 63, 71, 79, 87, 92, 95,
    103, 111, 112, 119, 124, 127, 135, 143, 151, 156, 159, 167, 175, 183,
    188, 191, 199, 207, 215, 220, 223, 231, 239, 240, 247, 252, 255, 263,
    271, 279, 284, 287, 295, 303, 311, 316, 319, 327, 335, 343 )

def squares( m ) :
    if m > 343 :
        print( 'choose a smaller number' )
    return m not in the failed
```

You may create the list of an arbitrary size using a simple formula: `4^i(8j+7), i >= 0, j >= 0`

Answer (score 0):

```
def threesquares(m):
    for p in range(0, m):
        for q in range(0, m):
            for r in range(0, m):
                if p*p + q*q + r*r == m:
                    return True
    return False
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add some description to explain what it does. It can be as short as just a line.

Answer (score 0):

def threesquares(m):
       if(m-7)%8==0 or (m-28)%8==0 :
              return(False)
       else:
              return(True)

Answer (score 0):

it will work

```
import math
def threesquares(m):
    n=int(math.log10(m))
    if n<1:
        n=1
    for a in range(n+1):
        b=0
        z=0
        while z<=m:
            z=((pow(4,a))*(8*b+7))
            if z==m:
                return False
            b+=1
    return True
```

i am using  Legendre's three-square theorem